# Options for generating electricity for autonomous platform while at sea?

Tags: energy

I am building an autonomous platform (2m x 2m) that I intend to deploy to the sea. To power various sensors and actuators I will make use of solar panels, but it occurred to me that there might be other sources of energy that could supplement the solar solution.

I got thinking about how the rocking motion of the vessel could be converted to energy, or how the waves could be harnessed. Something like this (see first image/animation), but on a smaller scale is what I was imagining: https://www.ecowavepower.com/

What products currently exist that are compatible for smallish (2m x 2m) platforms?

Comment: So many different wave energy systems are around... Or consider wind energy.

Comment: How is the platform constrained? Anchor? Free floating? Propulsion?

Comment: @Drew it is free floating. It will have propulsion.

Answer (score -1):

"Wave gliders" are wave- and solar-powered: https://www.liquid-robotics.com/wave-glider/how-it-works/

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with them. But that does not list the range of energy-generation products that I can explore for suitability.

Comment: @pookie then you should mention what you have considered and discarded in your original post so people don’t waste their time and effort on your behalf.

Comment: @SolarMike I explicitly asked for "options for generating electricity". I said that I will use solar and am looking into wave-power (I am not familiar with this tech). I did not ask for a ready-made platforms; I'm looking for OTS products (as mentioned in my post) that I can use to power an autonomous surface vehicle.

Comment: @John to avoid "link-rot" you are encouraged to quote directly from the source.